# Как запускать функцию paintEvent когда нужно?

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу программу на Qt c++ и мне нужно сделать запуск paintEvent при нажатии на кнопку, не понимаю как это сделать, в интернете пишут что все рисование должно происходить внутри этой функции, но тогда как мне вызвать ее в кнопку? Есть ли вариант просто расписать внутри этой функции что надо рисовать а потом при нажатии на кнопку просто вызвать??

P.S:
Пробовал реализовать через сигналы и слоты , вот так:

Заголовочный:

```
//MainWindow.h:

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPainter>
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
public slots:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

И сам cpp файл:

```
//MainWindow.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter painter(this); // Создаём объект отрисовщика
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::white, 1, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap));
    painter.drawLine(150,150,150,400);
    painter.drawLine(150,150,400,150);
    painter.drawLine(400,150,400,400);
    painter.drawLine(150,400,400,400);
}
```

Но Qt выдает следующее:

```
QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
        QPushButton::clicked() --> MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
```

Помогите пожалуйста, почему пишет тут ошибку и какие способы есть вообще решить эту проблему и рисовать при нажатии кнопки?

Comment: `QWidget::repaint()`?

Comment: @user7860670 о получилось! спасибо:) Тоесть я правильно понял что repaint вызывает данный метод paintEvent?

Comment: @user7860670, правильно. Посмотрите документацию: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#repaint. Там довольно кратко изложено, что делает эта функция, какие проблемы она может вызвать, и почему лучше стоит использовать `update()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я пользуюсь `QWidget::update()` можно ещё использовать `QWidget::repaint()` но народ говорит это не лучший выбор.

Вот код вызова:

```
void Compass::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
     
    ... // тут рисую 
}

 void Compass::set_pitch(int val)
{
    _myTexpr.m_pitch = val; // точка отрисовки 
   update(); // отрисовка по сути вызов paintEvent
}
```

вот сам класс :

```
class Compass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     explicit Compass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Compass();

    void razmer_kompas(int x, int y);
    void set_pitch(int val);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

    texnStructur _myTexpr; 
};
```